# Pooled T-Test for Binary Observations?

Tags: statistical-significance

I'm trying to compare two populations with binary variables, and I'm not sure how to do a t-test to compare them in R. I think I'm supposed to do a pooled t-test, but all of the methods I'm finding online are for sets of numeric values.

Basically, I have a population of x people, where n of them have black hair, and a population of y people, m of them have black hair, and I want to be able to determine if the difference in the rates is distinct. Any idea on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statistical tests are for when you have samples, but wish to infer things about the population(s) from which they are drawn (generally, whether they differ in some underlying population quantity), often by producing explicit estimates of the quantities concerned. If you have the two *populations* about which you wish to make those inferences, then there's no need to apply statistical methods -- you have the populations already, so just compare the quantities directly -- you already know them, no estimation involved.

If you were instead dealing with *random samples* from the populations of interest, then you wouldn't use a t-test. A two-sample proportions test or a chi-squared test would be the most common way to compare the two proportions. If one is a population and the other is a sample, you could use a one-sample proportions test (binomial test) or a chi-square goodness of fit test. In each case there are other tests that might be used instead.